# UI dropdown with GWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, user-interface, gwt

I need to add a dropdown for report generation in a page. There are other exisitng drop downs with the names "As Of Trades" "EOD.." etc. I need to add another one, lets say "DummyReport". The drop down should have only the Date option next to it, rather than "date From.. To", as is the case for other reports.

I am trying to remove the tradeDateRange member but it's not working. Can someone help me with this .The server side call is getting passed with correct parameters but I am not able to manipulate the UI

```
public class AffirmationStatistics extends MXVBox implements MXLazyComponent{

    private boolean m_initialized = false;
    private MXVBox m_statData;
    private Integer dateRange;
    private MXListGrid m_grid;
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT_YYYYMMDD = "yyyy-MM-dd" ;
    private MXComboBoxItem statChoiceComboBox= new MXComboBoxItem ();
    final MXDateRange tradeDateRange = new MXDateRange (new Date () );
    private volatile boolean m_exportOnClickEventInProgress = false;
    private MXListGridField m_branch_cd,
            m_account_cd,
            m_all_trades,
            m_same_day_trades,
            m_affermed,
            m_as_of_trades,
            m_account_num,
            m_affirmed_on_t,
            m_pct_affirmed_on_t,
            m_affirmed_on_t_plus_1,
            m_pct_affirmed_on_t_plus_1,
            m_affirmed_on_t_plus_2,
            m_pct_affirmed_on_t_plus_2,
            m_total_affirmed,
            m_total_count,
            m_settlement_date, m_wfs, m_wfs;
            
            private MXListGridField []m_gridFields_affirmed =
            {

            m_account_num = new MXListGridField (name: "agentinternalaccountnumber", title: "Account Number", 
            m_affirmed_on_t = new MXListGridField ( name: "affirmed_on_t", title: "Affirmed on T", 
            m_pct_affirmed_on_t = new MXListGridField ( name: "pct_affirmed_on_t", 
            m_affirmed_on_t_plus_1 = new MXListGridField ( name: "affirmed_on_t_plus_1",
            m_pct_affirmed_on_t_plus_1= new MXListGridField ( name: "pct_affirmed_on_t_plus_1",
            m_affirmed_on_t_plus_2 = new MXListGridField ( name: "affirmed_on_t_plus_2",
            m_pct_affirmed_on_t_plus_2= new MXListGridField ( name: "pct_affirmed_on_t_plus_2"
            m_total_affirmed = new MXListGridField ( name: "total_affirmed",
            m_total_count = new MXListGridField ( name: "total_count"
            };
            
            private MXListGridField [] m_gridFields_asof =
            {
                m_branch_cd = new MXListGridField ( name: "branch_cd",
                m_account_cd = new MXListGridField ( name: "branch_cd",
                m_all_trades = new MXListGridField (name: "all_trades",
                m_same_day_trades = new MXListGridField (name: "same_day_trades",
                m_affermed = new MXListGridField ( name: "affirmed"
                m_as_of_trades = new MXListGridField ( name: "as_of_trades",

                
            };
            
            




    private void getDateRange()
    {
        NObject request = new NObject();
        
        JSONServiceRequest.result("GetAffirmationDateRange", request,
        CallbackUtils.waiting("loading data...", new MAsyncCallback<NObject>() {
        
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(NObject result){
            Integer val = result.getAsInteger("data");
            if(val!=null){
                dateRange = val;
                .info("Value of date range returned " +dateRange);
            }
            else {
                s_errorinfo("Value of date range not returned " + dateRange);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
        {
            AffirmationsStatistics.s_log.error("unable to get date",caught);
            XC.warn(caught.getMessage());
        }
    }
        ));
    }
    
    @Override
    public void activate() {
        if(!m_initialized){
            getDateRange();
            
            
            MXHBox statSettings = new MXHBox();
            statSettings.setHeight(1);
            statSettings.setWidth(1);
            statSettings.setPadding(5);
            MXHBox statChoiceSection = new MXHBox();
            MXDynamicForm statChoiceForm = new MXDynamicForm();
            statChoiceForm.setCellPadding(1);
            statChoiceForm.setLayoutAlign(VerticleAlignment.CENTRE);
            
            LinkedHashMap<String,String> statusMap = new LinkedHashMap();
            statusMap.put("As of trades", "As of trades");
            statusMap.put("Affirmed trades", "Affirmed trades");
            statusMap.put("EOD Break Metric", "EOD Break Metric");
            statusMap.put("Sreet Trade Data", "Street Trade Data");
            
            
            statChoiceComboBox.setTitle("Statistic Type");
            statChoiceComboBox.setType("comboBox");
            statChoiceComboBox.setValueMap(statusMap);
            
            statChoiceComboBox.setTitle("Statistic Type");
            statChoiceComboBox.setType("combBox");
            statChoiceComboBox.setValueMap(statusMap);
            statChoiceComboBox.setDefaultValue("As of Trades");
            statChoiceComboBox.setWidth( 200 );
            
            statChoiceForm.setItems(statChoiceComboBox);
            statChoiceSection.addMember(statChoiceForm);
            
            MXHBox statDateRanges = new MXHBox();
            
            statDateRanges.setLayoutAlign(VerticleAlignment.CENTRE);
            
            tradeDateRange.setFromDateTitle("Trade Date From");
            tradeDateRange.setSyncInvertedDateRange(true);
            statDateRanges.addMember(tradeDateRange);
            
            final MXVBox statGridManipulation = new MXVBox();
            
            statGridManipulation.setLayoutAlign(VerticleAlignment.CENTRE);
            
            final MXButton refreshBtn = new MXButton("refreshBtn", Icon.getIcon(Icon.REFRESH));
            {
                statGridManipulation.setWidth(refreshBtn.getWidth());
                refreshBtn.setAlign(Alignment.CENTRE);
                refreshBtn.setTitle("Refresh");
                
                refreshBtn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
                        refresh(tradeDateRange.getStartDate(), tradeDateRange.getEndDate(),
                        statChoiceComboBox.getValueAsString());
                    }
                    
                });
                
                statGridManipulation.addMember(refreshBtn);
            }
            
            final MXHBox statActions = new MXHBox();
            
            statActions.setWidth(800);
            statActions.setHeight(25);
            statActions.setPadding(5);
            
            final MXButton m_exportBtn = new MXButton("exportToXLSX", Icon.getIcon(Icon.CSV_FILE));
            {
                m_exportBtn.setAlign(Alignment.LEFT);
                m_exportBtn.setTitle("Export to XLSX");
                m_exportBtn.setLayoutAlign(VerticleAlignment.CENTRE);
                
                m_exportBtn.addClickHandler(
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
                            if(m_grid != null)
                            {
                                m_exportOnClickEventInProgress = true;
                                exportToXLSXHangerLogic(m_grid, statChoiceComboBox.getValueAsString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    );
                    
                    statActions.addMember(m_exportBtn);
            }
            
            final MXButton m_exportBtnStreetData= new MXButton ("exportToXLSXStreetData", Icon.getIcon (Icon.CSV_FILE));
            exportBtnStreetData(m_exportBtnStreetData);
            
            statChoiceComboBox.addChangedHandler(new ChangedHandler()
        {

        @Override
        public void onChanged (ChangedEvent event) {
            if (statChoiceComboBox.getValueAsString() == "Street Trade Data") {
                statActions.addMember (m_exportBtnStreetData);
                statActions.removeMember (m_exportBtn);
                statGridManipulation.removeMember (refreshBtn);
                m_exportBtnStreetData.enable();
                if (m_grid != null) {
                    m_grid.destroy();
                    m_grid = initUI();
                    m_statData.addMember (n_grid);
                }   
            } else {
                    statActions.addMember(m_exportBtn);
                    statGridManipulation.addMember (refreshBtn);
                    statActions.removeMember (m_exportBtnStreetData);
            }
        }
    }
    );
    
        statSettings.addMember ( statChoiceSection);
        statSettings.addMember( statDateRanges);
        statSettings.addMember (statGridManipulation) ;
        addMember ( statSettings);
        
        m_statData = new MXVBox ();
        m_statData.setHeight (100);
        m_grid = initUI ();
        m_statData.addMember (m_grid);
        addMember (m_statData );
        addMember ( statActions);
        m_initialized = true;
        }
    }
    
    public MXListGrid createGrid() 
    {
        NObject request = new NObject();
        
        m_grid = new MXListGrid();
        
        JSONServiceRequest.result("GetAffirmationsStatisticsService",
                                    request,
                                    CallbackUtils.waiting("Loading detils...",
                                                        new MAsyncCallback<NObject()
                                                        {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onSuccess(NObject result) {m_grid = initUI();}
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
                                                            {
                                                                s_log.error(caught);
                                                                XC.warn("Failure");
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        ));
        return m_grid;
    }
    
    private MXListGrid initUI()
    {
        m_grid = new MXListGrid ();
        m_grid.setBorder( MXUtils.COMMON_BORDER);
        m_grid.setHeight100();
        m_grid.setSelection Type ( SelectionStyle.SIMPLE);
        m_grid.setCanExpandRecords (false);
        m_grid.setShowAllRecords (true);
        m_grid.setAlternateRecordStyles (true);
        m_grid.setShowFilterEditor (false);
        m_grid.setCanEdit(false);
        m_grid.setEditByCell(false);
        m_grid.setEditEvent ( ListGridEditEvent.CLICK);
        m_grid.setListEndEditAction( RowEndEditAction.DONE);
        m_grid.setAutoSaveEdits (true);
        m_grid.setModalEditing (true);
        m_grid.setAllowFilterExpressions (true);
        m_grid.setCanMultiGroup(true);
        m_grid.setCanMultiSort(true);
        m_grid.setCanFocus (true);
        m_grid.setCanSelectAll(true);
        m_grid.setFilterOnkeypress (false);
        m_grid.setAutoFitFiieldwidths (true);
        m_grid.setAutoFitWidthApproach (AutoFitWidthApproach.BOTH);
        
        return m_grid;

    }
        private void replaceGrid (NArray data )
            {
                if (m_grid != null )
                    {
                        m_statData.removeMember (m_grid);
                        m_grid.destroy ( ) ;
                    }    
            m_grid = initUI ();
            
            if (data != null)
            {
        
                if (statChoiceComboBox.getValueAsString () == "As Of Trades") {
                    m_grid.setDefaultFields (m_gridFields_asof);
                    m_grid.setData( MXRecordList.toRecordArray(data));
                    m_grid.setDataSource(new MXSimpleDS(data, m_gridFields_asof));
                }
                if (statChoiceComboBox.getValueAsString() == "Affirmed Trades") {
                    m_grid.setDefaultFields (m_gridFields_affirmed);
                    m_grid.setData( MXRecordList.toRecordArray(data));
                    m_grid.setDataSource(new MXSimpleDS (data, m_gridFields_affirmed));
                }
                if (statChoiceComboBox.getValueAsString() == "EOD Break Metrics") {
                    m_grid.setDefaultFields (m_gridFields_eod);
                    m_grid, setData( MXRecordList.toRecordArray (data));
                    m_grid.setDataSource(new MXSimpleDS (data, m_gridFields_eod));
                }    
                    m_grid.setAutoFetchData(true);

            }
            
            m_statData.addMember(m_grid);
    
}

    private void refresh(
        Date p_tradeDateStart,
        Date p_tradeDateEnd,
        String p_choise
        )
        {
            NObject request = new NObject( ) ;
            DateTimeFormat dateFormat= DateTimeFormat.getFormat (DATE_FORMAT_YYYYMMDD);
            request.put ( "startingTradeDate", dateFormat.format (p_tradeDateStart ) ) ;
            request.put(name: "endingTradeDate" , dateFormat. format (p_tradeDateEnd ));
            request.put(name: "choise", p_choise);

            JSONServiceRequest.result("GetAffirmationsStatisticsService",
                                    request,
                                    CallbackUtils.waiting("Loading detils...",
                                                        new MAsyncCallback<NObject>()
                                                        {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onSuccess(NObject result)
                                                            
                                                            {   NArray data = result.getAsArray("data");
                                                                replaceGrid(data);
                                                            }
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
                                                            {
                                                                s_log.error(caught);
                                                                XC.warn("Failure");
                                                            }
                                                        }    
                                      )
                                    );
        }
        
        private void exportToXLSXHangerLogic(final MXListGrid p_grid, String p_originTab)
        {
            if (resultSet.lengthIsKnown () == false)
            {
                XC.warn ("Total number of rows not known. Only aware of \"" + resultSet.getLength () + "\" rows.");
            }
            else
            {
                s_log.info ("resultSet elements =" + resultSet.getLength () );
            }
            p_grid.addDataArrivedHandler (new DataArrivedHandler ()
                                        {
                                            @Override 
                                            public void onDataArrived ( DataArrivedEvent dataArrivedEvent )
                                            {
                                                if (m_exportOnClickEventInProgress &&
                                                resultSet.rangeIsLoaded (0, resultSet.getLength ( ) ) )
                                                {
                                                    exportToXLSX (p_grid.getFields (), resultSet ) ;
                                                    m_exportOnClickEventInProgress = false;
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }
                        );
                        
            if (m_exportOnClickEventInProgress && resultSet.rangeIsLoaded (0, resultSet.getLength()))
            {
                exportToXLSX (p_grid.getFields (), resultSet);
                m_exportOnClickEventInProgress = false;

            }
        }
        
        private void exportToXLSX (ListGridField [] p_visibleFields, RecordList p_recordList )
        {
            NArray visibleFieldList = new NArray ( ) ;
            for (int i = 0; i < p_visibleFields.length; i++)
            {
                if (p_visibleFields [i].getName().equals (“_checkboxField") == false)
                {
                    NObject metadata = new NObject ( ) ;
                    
                    metadata.put (name: "fieldName" , p_visibleFields [i].getName () );
                    metadata.put (name: "fieldTitle", , p_visibleFields [i].getTitle () );
                    metadata.put (name: "listGridFieldTypeEnum", p_visibleFields [i].getType ().name () );
                    
                    visibleFieldList.push (metadata );
            

                }
        }
        
        NArray rows = new NArray ( ) ;
        for(Record r: p_recordList.toArray ( ) )
        {
            NObject row = new NObject ();
            for (int i = 0; i < visibleFieldList.size (); i++)
            {
               String attribute= r.getAttributeAsString ( visibleFieldList.getAsObject (i).getAsString ("fieldName"));
               
               if (attribute == null)
               {
                   attribute = "";
               }
               
               row.put (visibleFieldList.getAsObject (i).getAsString ( "fieldName"), attribute) ;
            } 
            rows.push(row);
            
        }
        
        NObject request = new NObject ();
        request.put ( "visibleFields" ,visibleFieldList ) ;
        request.put( "rows" , rows);
        request.put ( "origin" , statChoiceComboBox.getValueAsString());
        
        JSONServiceRequest.result("GetAffirmationsStatisticsService",
                                    request,
                                    CallbackUtils.waiting("Generating XLSX file...",
                                                         new MAsyncCallback< NObject > ()
                                                         {
                                                             @Override
                                                             public void onSuccess (NObject result )
                                                             {
                                                                 final String url = result.getAsString ( "url" );
                                                                MXBrowser.openDocument ( url, IsPDF: false);

                                                             }

                                                             
                                                         }
                                    )
                                    
        );
        
        }   
        
        public void exportButtonStreetData(Date p_tradeDateStart, Date p_tradeDateEnd, String p_choise)
        {
            NObject request = new NObject( ) ;
            DateTimeFormat dateFormat= DateTimeFormat.getFormat (DATE_FORMAT_YYYYMMDD);
            request.put ( "startingTradeDate", dateFormat.format (p_tradeDateStart ) ) ;
            request.put(name: "endingTradeDate" , dateFormat. format (p_tradeDateEnd ));
            request.put(name: "choise", p_choise);
            
            JSONServiceRequest.result("GetAffirmationsStatisticsService",
                                    request,
                                    CallbackUtils.waiting("Loading detils...",
                                                        new MAsyncCallback<NObject>()
                                                        {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onSuccess(NObject result)
                                                            
                                                            {   NArray data = result.getAsArray("data");
                                                                NArray request = data.getAsObject(index :0);
                                                                JSONServiceRequest.result("GetAffirmationsStatisticsService",
                                                                                            request,
                                                                                            CallbackUtils.waiting("Generating XLSX file...", 
                                                                                            new MAsyncCallback<NObject>(){ 
                                                                                                @Override
                                                                                                public void onSuccess(NObject result){
                                                                                                    final String url = result.getAsString("url");
                                                                                                    MXBrowser.openDocument(url,false);
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            }));
                    
                                                         }     
                                                         @Override
                                                         public void onFailure(Throwable caught){
                                                             s_log.error(caught);
                                                             XC.warn(caught.getMessage());
                                                         }
                                                        }));  
                                                        
        }   
        
        
        @Override 
        public void suspend()
        {
            
        }
        
        public void exportBtnStreetData(MXButton exportBtnStreetData)
        {
            
            exportBtnStreetData.setAlign (Alignment.LEFT);
            exportBtnStreetData.setTitle("Export To XLSX Street Data");
            exportBtnStreetData.setLayoutAlign (VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
            
            exportBtnStreetData.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            
            
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                if (tradeDateRange.getStartDate() == null && tradeDateRange.getEndDate() == null) {
                    XC. warn("You must supply start and end trade date");
                }
                else if (tradeDateRange.getStartDate() == null || tradeDateRange.getEndDate() == null) {
                    XC.warn("You must supply start and end trade date");
                }
                
                else if (AffirmationsUtils.validateDateRange (tradeDateRange.getStartDate(), 
                    tradeDateRange.getEndDate(), dateRange)) {
                    exportButtonStreetData(tradeDateRange.getStartDate(), tradeDateRange.getEndDate(),
                    statChoiceComboBox.getValueAsString());
                }
                else 
                {
                    XC.warn("Trade date range should not exceed dateRange + " days");
                }
            }    
        });
                


        }
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
}
```

I tried to add clickhandler event for "Dummy Report" and remove the traddeDateRange.from_date memeber but it removed it for all existing drop downs

Comment: Could you create smaller piece of code presenting the issue ?